# WCF and WebBrowser. Threading problem

Tags: wcf, iis, webbrowser-control

I have a dll which parses some web site. This component uses WebBrowser control from Windows forms with using Navigate() method.

Also I have a WCF hosting in IIS 7 and with basicHttpBinding.

But when I call my WCF method which use the dll with WebBrower  from client I have such bug message:

ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

Is any way to resolve this unpleasant situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furtunately, I found an answer for the question. This code helps me:

```
    [STAThread]
    public Good GrabGood(string link)
    {
        _link = link;
        var t = new Thread(Grab); 
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
        t.Start(); 
        t.Join();

        return _good;
    }
    private Good _good;
    private string _link;
    private void Grab()
    {
        var grabber = new GoodsGrabber();
        try
        {
            _good = grabber.GrabGood(_link);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _good = null;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And such attributes for the class like:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
```

In any option variation didn't help me.

Comment: We are in your same situation, in terms of needing to run `WebBrowser` behind a WCF interface. Creating the thread in this manner does get around the STA problem, but the `WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event doesn't raise before `Thread.Join()` returns control. Are you blocking inside `GoodsGrabber` to ensure that whatever you want to actually do with the web page is happening before WCF returns?

Comment: See full code here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739978/generated-image-of-html-page-not-showing-the-gradient-color-in-the-generated-ima)